# Which is better Driver and Signal for UIButton tap event?

Tags: rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm new to RxSwift and RxCocoa. In my project, UIButton tap event is handled with `rx.tap.asDriver()` in many places but I wander that `Signal` is better in that case.

My recognition is:

- Driver is for state or variable
- Signal is for event

Please give me advice. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

A Driver emits its previous value on subscription whereas a Signal doesn't. It's rather rare to want to receive a previous button tap under any circumstances.

So yea, Driver isn't really appropriate for buttons. `Driver<Void>` in general doesn't make too much sense IMO.